# Third party OSGi library dependency conflict

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

In our Eclipse based product we're introducing a new third party plugin that depends on ANTLR v3.2+.

We have an existing plugin, also third party (openarchitectureware), that requires ANTLR v3.0. The problem is that the openarchitectureware plugins don't specify a dependency version range:

```
Require-Bundle: org.openarchitectureware.core.workflow,org.apache.comm ons.logging,
org.antlr.runtime,org.apache.log4j;resolution:=optional
```

This means they try to use the latest version of ANTLR, 3.2, and break.

Is there any way, without changing the openarchitectureware plugins, to force them to resolve against ANTLR 3.0 even if a newer version is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You will have to change the jar to add the correct meta data. You should also report this issue at openarchitectureware. So they can produce correct artifacts for newer versions.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's what I was expecting. I think the openarchitectureware project is defunct so I guess we'll have to change them ourselves.

Comment: You could write a ResolverHook, https://osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/hooks/resolver/package-summary.html, to force the bundle to resolve to the old version of the dependency, but that would be like killing an ant with a gun :-)